# Trouble choosing tense when "until" is used

Tags: grammar

> "We couldn’t put down the new floor till the plumber **had
>   finished**."
>
> "We couldn’t put down the new floor till the plumber **finished**."
>
> "I wait until he **finishes**."
>
> "I wait until he **has finished**"

I don't understand how I can choose the correct tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "correct". All of these are grammatical; but with a continuing process, the perfect is more common.

So, with a point event, it is common to use a simple tense

> I'll wait until he gets here.

and a perfect for a continuing event that reaches an end

> I'll wait until he has finished.

But the other way round is also possible:

> I'll wait until he has got here.
>   I'll wait until he finishes.

[One other point, that you didn't ask about: with most verbs, the so-called "present tense" is not a present tense at all, but a timeless or habitual tense. So in normal speech "I wait" is used only in a habitual sense. Here you want either "I'm waiting" or "I'll wait".]